# The method '>=' was called on null. Receiver: null

Tags: flutter

So, I figured out that the mistake producing the error is the **double _bmi** inside the **calculateBMI()** method. However, I would like to know why including double produces this error? What is the logical process?

```
import 'dart:math';

class CalculatorBrain {
  CalculatorBrain({this.height, this.weight});

  final int height;
  final int weight;
  double _bmi;

  String calculateBMI() {
    double _bmi = height / pow(height / 100, 2);
    return _bmi.toStringAsFixed(1);
  }

  String getResult() {
    if (_bmi >= 25.0) {
      return 'Overweight';
    } else if (_bmi > 18.5) {
      return 'Normal';
    } else {
      return 'Underweight';
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: `calculateBMI` sets a local `_bmi` variable and not the `_bmi` member variable.  The member variable is never assigned a value and is always `null`.

Comment: you just need to use `calculateBMI()` method in `getResult()` instead og `_bmi` variable. But there you get type exception. So, you just need to parse it to double and bingo, It works.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fron the `calculateBMI()` function, you have redeclared the `_bmi` variable `double _bmi = height / pow(height / 100, 2);`.
It's supposed to be:

```
_bmi = height / pow(height / 100, 2);
```

Comment: I think answer might needs to improve a little bit.